# -webkit-backface-visibility disrupts <body>'s background rendering, only without cache

Tags: html, css, webkit

[If you want to check out the problem for yourself, go here. You'll need to disable cache if you want to see the bug more than once](http://lukes.comyr.com)

I have a website that looks like this:
[image: What the website should look like]

Or should look like this, and it manages to render fine pretty much every time, apart from the first time you load the page:

[image: What the website looks like when you load it for the first time]

As it turns out, if you try to load the website without cache (i.e for the first time), the 's background gets cut off at the top, but a small patch appears around half of a particular element.

The element in question is an absolute element, placed behind it's parent element but adjusted with javascript to be in the exact same position and height. The class is called "blur", and the reason it does this is to blur everything behind the element but not the content of the same element it is in. It looks a little something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="blur">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
```

The style associated with .blur:

```
.blur {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url("mavericks.jpg");

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now if I comment out -webkit-backface-visibiltiy: hidden, the issue is immediately resolved. However, without hiding the backface the intro animation becomes incredibly sluggish, and moreover the background of the body isn't the backface part of the blur element, and shouldn't be hidden, as far as I am aware. What's even odder, is that even if the height or width of this element is set to 0, the rendering problem still remains.

I have a strong feeling that this is some sort of webkit bug, but if someone can help me find a workaround or find a substitute for -webkit-backface-visibility, I would appreciate it greatly, as without it the animations look like crap. Feel free to poke around the source of the website. Tested in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 and Safari 7.0

Comment: For some reason - when I take the backface-visiblity off - it doesn't do what you say it does. It's blazing fast on my end.

Comment: @LloanAlas you’re talking about the intro animation right? If it plays at all, that is